# Understanding performance of two Matrix rotation algorithms

Tags: c#, algorithm

My lack of in depth understanding of the fundamentals has taken a toll on these types of problem solving challenges.

The HackerRank matrix rotation problem is a very fun one to solve. I recommend people who are trying to enrich their coding skills to use hackerrank (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/matrix-rotation-algo)

The problem summary is that you are given an R x C matrix of integers where the minimum of R and C must be even. You have to rotate the matrix anti-clockwise x number of times. Rotation applies to the elements of the matrix, not the matrix dimension in case it is not clear.

So I solved this problem with two algorithms. They are both very similar in that you can imagine the matrix like layers of onions where you loop through each layer, and rotate the elements in that layer. The number of rotations is simply x % (count of elements in that layer) so if you are given x=1,000,000 it doesn't make sense to repeat full rotations.

The first one, which is the fastest is:
https://codetidy.com/8002/

The second one, does not loop through the number of rotations but instead does some heavy logic and math to figure out where to move an element to.
https://codetidy.com/8001/

So when I was writing the second one, I assumed that it would be crazy faster, because you don't iterate through maximum number of rotations in each layer. However, it ended up faring slower.

I don't quite understand why. I logged the number of iterations in a console and the first one does 50x more iterations, but is faster.

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you use `ref int[][] matrix` for the `Move()` parameter, rather than just `int[][] matrix`? You're not assigning to `matrix` inside the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of iterations is not everything. Here are a few general things that might affect the performance.

One important thing to keep in mind with arrays and matrices are cache hits. If your operations generate lots of cache hits they will seem orders of magnitude faster. To get cache hits you usually need to go in the memory order. For an array that is sequentially forward. For a matrix it means incrementing the lowest index first. To get misses you need to jump around in increments larger than the size of the cacheline (CPU dependent). Fun experiment: benchmark `for (i...) for (j...) ++m[i][j]` and `for (i...) for (j..) ++m[j][i]` to see the difference.

In your case I would guess that the faster approach has very linear access on the horizontal parts at least.

Then there's branch prediction. Modern CPUs pipeline the instructions to make better use of the existing hardware. Branches (IFs) break the pipeline since you don't know which path to take (that instruction is still executing). As an optimization the compiler/CPU pick one and start processing and if the condition result is the other way it will throw everything away and restart processing. Checking something that usually gives the same result (like `i<n`) will be faster than something that's harder to predict.

These are some lowlevel reasons why the simpler approach might seem faster. Add some higher level reasons (like compiler not optimizing the code the way you expect) and you get results like this.

An important note: The complexity reflects the asymptotically behavior. Yes, the second approach will be faster for a **sufficiently large** matrix, and it's very likely that the sizes used for this problem are not sufficiently large.

Comment: This is the answer I'm looking for! You are right the highest the rows or cols can get up to is 1000. That isn't a very large matrix.